# Command-line web browser

Tags: gratis, open-source, web-browser

I'm looking for a command-line web browser.

Requirements:

- Free and open source
- Runs on Debian
- Lightweight (under 50 MB)
- Supports CSS & JS
- Renders images (libcaca?)
- Has colors
- Doesn't use famebuffer or X
- Extendible with extensions

Answer (score 3):

There is [links](http://links.twibright.com/features.php).

It's Free Software, runs on [Debian](http://packages.ubuntu.com/links2), renders images (in graphics mode), colours, and doesn't necessarily use the framebuffer.

However, I think it lacks extensions.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't support CSS & JS, doesn't render images, doesn't have colors, doesn't have extensions...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/).

It certainly is Free Software and runs on [Debian](http://packages.ubuntu.com/w3m).

It renders images with certain terminals, has colours and doesn't use framebuffer.

I don't think there are extensions, though.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't support CSS & JS, doesn't render images, doesn't have colors, doesn't have extensions...